# I/flutter logs are showing from previous app

Tags: flutter

I/flutter logs are showing even i commented print statements. If i run run new app also, old app logs are showing in console. No luck with flutter clean command.

Can any one suggest to solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you on the stable channel?

Comment: No. I am in master channel and updating frequently whenever i got upgrade flutter. My current version is 1.13.1-pre.92

Comment: this happened even with me after updating flutter to 1.13.5 hotfix

Comment: Then it will be issue with flutter versions. Flutter team will resolve.

Comment: @MaheshPeri have you opened an issue?

Comment: No. Will check for next version also. If still that issue is there, i will open

Answer (score 9):

Took me (many) hours to figure this out.

```
% flutter help logs
```

Show log output for running Flutter apps.

> Usage: flutter logs [arguments]
>   -h, --help     Print this usage information.
>   -c, --clear    Clear log history before reading from logs.

Run `flutter help` to see global options.

Try:
`flutter logs -c  (to clear, run in the project directory)`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO :) Please try to format your answer, especially by marking code and terminal commands as such

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use that package that called **pretty_logger** it gives you colorful logs,
and it shows log only in Dev and Debug modes.

Add the following to your pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  pretty_logger: ^1.0.0
```

Import the package.

```dart
import 'package:pretty_logger/pretty_logger.dart';
```

Usage

```dart
  PLog.yellow('yellow');
```